# Did the others learn what Glória did?

Tags: 3-percent

During the time when Glória was at odds with Michele, Marcela was able to talk Glória into

> releasing her from her cell at the Shell and setting the building on fire.

Toward the end of the series, when Joana, Natália, Rafael and Elisa had been captured by André, Glória

> helped them escape together with Ariel

and the others seemed to be happy to have her full support again.

We know Glória confided in Ariel at one point, but did she tell anyone else? **Did the other members of the Cause know**

> that the Shell was destroyed by Glória herself

**? Did Michele know?**

One more data point: When Michele questioned Xavier and Glória on which one of them sabotaged the Shell, she seemed to suspect something about Glória's loyalty, though of course, that was also fueled by Glória's earlier betrayal and temporary takeover of the Shell.